# shiro session store using dao across multiple web applications

Tags: java, session, serialization, shiro

Shiro's SessionDAO is used to store session in a db(as a blob).
This session is used across multiple web applications(shiro enabled)
Now the problem is each web application is trying to set attributes(custom classes) in the session.
when tried to deserialize in other web application, it throws back ClassDefNotFoundException as it doesn't exist.
Is there any way I can solve this?
What should be the ideal approach?

Answer (score 0):

Separate your singular session into multiple sessions.  Start with a globally accessible session that contains the user's principal and the application specific keys for all other web applications that are using the same session (and nothing else).  Then when accessing an isolated web application create a new "session" in the cache and put the key for it into the global session.  Then when a user accesses the isolated web application a filter should retrieve the key from the global session and bind the isolated web application specific session to the current thread context (and then remove it after execution has completed).

```
main-user-session
|
+--user-principal
|
+--app1-user-session-key
|
+--app2-user-session-key


void filter (HttpRequest req, HttpResponse resp) {
    var app1key = sessionCache.get("main-user-session-key")
                              .get("app1-user-session-key");
    Session app1Sess = sessionCache.get(app1key);
    threadContext.bind("SESSION", app1Sess);
    try {
      execute(request, response);
    } finally (Exception e) {
      threadContext.unbind("SESSION");
    }
}
```